# HTTP response code indicates tag failed to fire: Status 404. Publishing new version in GTM does not work

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I installed the GA4 via GTM. Everything worked fine, I already implemented a few custom events. Now I see that the GA4 is no longer retrieving data due to the error:

> The HTTP response code indicates that the tag could not be triggered: Status 404. This could be due to an empty or unpublished container.

I already tried to publish and create a new version (even though it was empty), but the 404 error persists. The configuration tag for GA4 and other custom events are fired correctly - checked with Google Tag Assitant.

Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Where are you seeing that error message?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller 
In both Chrome Console (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()) and Google Tag Assistant Legacy.

Comment: wow, this is an interesting one. Please make sure you're not using an add blocker. Now open your Network tab and confirm that a 404 is there. Now check what the 404 is for: is it for the GA4 ?collect call or for gtm call? Provide screenshots.

Comment: @BNazaruk I turned off the add blocker and it still did not work, when I deleted the plugin it worked. That's weird. Anyway, now it works fine :) Thanks a lot!